# How to center an icon in QStandardItemModel?

Tags: qt, pyqt4, pyqt5

```
def data(self, index, role):
    if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
        if index.column() == 0:
            return QApplication.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DialogYesButton if self.item(index.row()).valid else QStyle.SP_DialogNoButton)
    elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
        if index.column() == 0:
            return QVariant(Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

The icons are displayed well but they are not centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with QStyledItemDelegate.

```
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
        QApplication.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DialogYesButton if index.data().valid else QStyle.SP_DialogNoButton).paint(painter, option.rect)
```